# iwlist inconsistent format for quality and signal?

Tags: wifi

I noticed when I run `iwlist wlan1 scan` I sometimes get lines like this:

```
Quality=0/100  Signal level=62/100
```

But other times I get lines like this:

```
Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
```

Why does the second example use `:` instead of `=`?

Is the colon only used if `iwlist` failed to get the values?

Comment: Not an answer, but try `iw wlan1 scan` or `iw wlan1 scan dump` (doesn't do a new scan) instead - it will have a consistent format.

Comment: @dirkt I don't know why but my target device doesn't seem to work with `iw` I get back `No such device (-19)`. The device has `iw` version 3.4. I think it might be that the interface doesn't support the `nl80211` driver but I'm not sure. (using `RTL8188` wireless chip)

Comment: My USB WLAN adapter is also not recognised by `iw`. That "new" tool (since when already?) doesn't seem to be stable or reliable yet, so `iwlist` is the way to go, really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle it seems that your basic premise is [correct](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521364/what-is-the-quality-of-a-wi-fi-access-point)

The interface for [wireless tools for linux](https://hewlettpackard.github.io/wireless-tools/Linux.Wireless.Extensions.html) is at

```
cat /proc/net/wireless
```

and gives your basic parameters including link/level/noise

```
Inter-| sta-|   Quality        |   Discarded packets               | Missed | WE
 face | tus | link level noise |  nwid  crypt   frag  retry   misc | beacon | 22
wlan0: 0000   66.  -44.  -256        0      0      0      0      0        0
```

and if there is a viable connection with traffic then more data regarding the link and traffic is at

```
cat /proc/net/dev
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
    lo:  442540    7574    0    0    0     0          0         0   442540    7574    0    0    0     0       0          0
 wlan0: 11837166   18597    0    0    0  5272          0         0  2650725   18388    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

So if `iwlist` sees 0/0/0 for link/level/noise in `/proc/net/wireless` it just reports them and doesn't process any data from there or `/proc/dev/net` for the other statistics.

It may also help to understand that

```
Quality=0/100
```

is the link quality (the proportion of correctly received packets) while

```
Quality:0
```

Is some measure of signal quality (`/proc/net/wireless`) reported from your card.

Same word, different usage.

I looked all that up because of your question, but couldn't find the source code for `iwlist` to double check. Thanks for the education.

Comment: Thanks lots of interesting information, still reading. I think this might be the source code for `iwlist` you mentioned at the end: https://github.com/HewlettPackard/wireless-tools/blob/master/wireless_tools/iwlist.c

Comment: I think I learn more from other peoples questions than my own. Well observed question by the way. I'd ever noticed that until you pointed it out.