# How is /proc/net/wireless a "clone" of /proc/net/dev?

Tags: kernel, wifi

I'm reading through the [documentation for Linux Wireless Extensions](https://hewlettpackard.github.io/wireless-tools/Linux.Wireless.Extensions.html), linked in a [related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407768/16792).

It says:

> `/proc/net/wireless` is designed to give some wireless specific
>   statistics on each wireless interface in the system. This entry is in
>   fact a clone of `/proc/net/dev` which gives the standard driver
>   statistics.

The formats of these two files is completely different:

`/proc/net/dev`:

```
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
    lo: 13094103   37388    0    0    0     0          0         0 13094103   37388    0    0    0     0       0          0
  eth0: 539566809  524165    0    0    0     0          0         0 47595494  365161    0    0    0     0       0          0
 tunl0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
  gre0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
  sit0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
ip6tnl0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
 wlan1: 41003557  351105    0 49935    0     0          0         0 525781104  475280    0   35    0     0       0          0
  tun0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

`/proc/net/wireless`:

```
Inter-| sta-|   Quality        |   Discarded packets               | Missed | WE
 face | tus | link level noise |  nwid  crypt   frag  retry   misc | beacon | 22
 wlan1: 0000   21.  -66.  -256.       0      0      0      0      0        0
```

Does this mean that the values in `/proc/net/wireless` are generated by doing arithmetic on the values for `wlan1` in `/proc/net/dev`?

Comment: Nice to see you again :-) The statement about the two files being clones is repudiated in the comments to the [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521364/what-is-the-quality-of-a-wi-fi-access-point).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This entry is in fact a clone of `/proc/net/dev` which gives the standard driver statistics.

is an over-simplification. The comment in [the code implementing `/proc/net/wireless`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/wireless/wext-proc.c) is more accurate:

> This interface is a pure clone of `/proc/net/dev` (in `net/core/dev.c`).
>     The content of the file is basically the content of "`struct iw_statistics`".

The *interface* is a clone, *i.e.* the look: columns, with a header using pipe separators. But the content is completely different (and you can’t calculate it from `/proc/net/dev`).

Comment: But what about on this line, it seems that `/proc/net/dev` is fetched to get some information? Maybe the code I'm linking is unrelated to the actual generation of `/proc/net/wireless` though? https://github.com/HewlettPackard/wireless-tools/blob/c7b2e81e6d53daac413a19d5446ab68b8395c849/wireless_tools/iwlib.c#L242

Comment: No, that has nothing to do with `/proc/net/wireless`. I linked to the code involved for that in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The information kept in

```
/proc/net/dev
```

is explained in detail [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20180522173537/http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2000/11/16/LinuxAdmin.html)

It is the cumulative traffic information since the link went up not the instantaneous device information available in

```
/proc/net/wireless
```