# Can wpa_cli scan results show signal quality (e.g. as n/N) instead of signal level (in dBm)?

Tags: linux, wpa-cli

On my laptop `wpa_cli` scan results are expressed in very low dBm values, i.e. *all less than -50dBm*, the strongest (**57/70**) of which is **-53dBm**, which I find weird, by the way. Is there a way to have scan results return signal strength instead, just like `iwlist scan`, which returns both signal quality as `N/70` and strength in dBm ?

Comment: Get closer to the AP and you should be able to get up to -30 dBm easily. Really close and you'll get even higher. For some more details on "qality", see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407754/iwlist-inconsistent-format-for-quality-and-signal and also https://askubuntu.com/questions/521364/what-is-the-quality-of-a-wi-fi-access-point (None of this answers your question, of course)

Comment: Thanks @derobert . I am approx. 5m away from the access point and behind a (light) wall. But my point rather is about the seemingly low values, which suggest 5.3E-5 milliwatt (if my calculations are correct), i.e. 50 picowatt and closest to the access point! Does that really make sense? What power ranges are expected on a wider scale (geographically speaking)?

Comment: yep, through a wall that sounds right. Depending on the card and the amount of radio noise it'll probably work down to almost -90dBm.

Comment: I was wrong, it's nanowatts not picowatts... (D'oh) Still quite low as a power measurement. Anyway thanks for the info :-) .

Comment: well, not low for radio really... E.g., a strong GPS signal is somewhere around -110dBm, and some receivers can apparently go down to -140dBm or lower. -30 to -90 is probably the range you can expect to see with WiFi. Might get higher if you set the client a meter or so, clear line of sight, from the AP (much closer than that and you may saturate the radio causing it to not work well).

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree, just that the distance with GPS emitters is several orders of magnitude bigger. Access point's spit a few dozens of milliwatts (like 70 in my case) a few feet away.